# Order By and Distinct in same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using sql server 2008, i have the following data

```
sNames             sDate 
(varchar(MAX))    (date)
==========     =============
 ALS           10/02/2012
 SSP           11/03/2012
 MRP           11/05/2012
 ALS           14/06/2012
 ALS           04/10/2012
 ALS           03/11/2012
 MRP           05/09/2012
 PPL           18/08/2012
```

I want to order the list by sDate in desc but must show distinct sNames. kindly guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the latest dates for duplicate `sNames` you can do

```
select sNames, max(sDate)
from your_table
group by sNames
order by max(sDate) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
Select distinct snames 
from yourtable 
order by sdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(sDate),sname from yourTable 
group by sname 
order by max(sDate) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sNames FROM <YOUR TABLE NAME> ORDER BY sDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sNames, sDate  
FROM <tableName>  
ORDER BY sDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sName,sDate From [your_table] order by sDate Desc
```

Comment: It's not clear, but I think that the requirement is to show a list of *distinct* sName values.